# Share retain state across multiple Unmanaged instances

Tags: swift

I'm invoking a C library from Swift that takes in an opaque pointer and a callback function. The C library then passes that opaque pointer to the callback function. In order to create the opaque pointer, I'm using the Unmanaged type provided by the Swift standard library, which looks something like this:

```
func callback(
  opaque: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
) {
  let queue: DispatchQueue = // ...
  let thing = Unmanaged<MyThing>.fromOpaque(opaque).takeRetainedValue()
  queue.async { [weak thing] in
    guard let thing else { return }
    // Use thing here
  }
}

func newThing() -> MyThing {
  let thing = MyThing()
  let opaque = Unmanaged.passUnretained(thing).toOpaque()
  my_c_library_function(opaque, callback) // invokes callback(opaque)
  return thing
}

class MyThing {
}
```

The issue I'm having is that `thing` gets deallocated at the end of `callback`. I guess this is because I create a new Unmanaged instance, call takeRetained, and then the value is released at the end of callback. The fact that I still have a reference to `thing` inside of `newThing` isn't considered as part of the `Unmanaged` instance in `callback`.

Is there a way to solve this problem? The main issue I'm trying to solve with this pattern is getting a pointer to MyThing back from the C library, and then using that pointer in an async block. Ideally I'd like to only perform the async block if the caller to `newThing` still had a reference to it.

Comment: How about `.passRetained`? You want the instance to stay alive even after `newThing` returns. Be careful though, if the callback isn't called for some reason, you'd get a memory leak.

Comment: You could also try calling `CFRetain` in your C function, if that is an option for you.

Comment: Hmm I guess the semantics of the methods aren't entirely clear to me. Wouldn't it be safer to use `passUnretained` and then `takeUnretained`? I think the issue is that I'm passing unretained, but then taking retained so the retain count is incorrect.

Comment: Wait, hold on, I seem to have misunderstood. The C function is not asynchronous?

Comment: Right now, the C function is not async, but it could be in the future. So let's assume the C function is async. Is it possible to hold something akin to a weak reference to Swift objects in C?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want *weak* references? You obviously want to *retain* the reference here, which is not what `weak` does.

Comment: I don't really want to retain a reference unless the caller to `newThing` still has a reference. The general flow is this: someone calls `newThing`, which creates a `MyThing` instance and starts some async work in C. When the work is done, `callback` is invoked. However, there isn't a reason to retain the result of `MyThing` just to invoke `callback`. If the caller of `newThing` wants to deinit the result, I don't want to prevent that from happening. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the issue is that I'm passing unretained, but then taking retained so the retain count is incorrect.

Indeed, this is one of the issues. If the C function is synchronous, you should pass unretained and take unretained, because there is no need to retain a reference. The instance of `myThing` will remain alive because `newThing` is retaining it, when `callback` is called.

However, the way you are using `queue.async` is problematic. You should not weakly capture `thing` there. Since `queue.async` is asynchronous, it will run after `callback` has returned. At that point, the instance will already have been deallocated, and your `guard` will fail and return immediately.

You should just do:

```
queue.async {
    // do things with thing, e.g.
    print(thing)
}
```

This causes the closure passed to `async` to retain `thing`.

---

If the C function is asynchronous, you should pass retained and take retained instead. This is because in this case the callback will run *after* `newThing` returns, at which point nothing will be retaining the instance of `thing`.

Similarly, you also should not weakly capture `thing` in `queue.async`.